# Proving that a set of polynomials P2 is a subspace of P3

Tags: linear-algebra

The questions specifically says:

Show that the set $W$ of all polynomials in $P_2$ (polynomials of degree $2$ or less) such that $P(1) = 0$ is a subspace of $P_3$.

To prove this I am assuming it must follow two axioms:

- closed under scalar multiplication
- closed under addition

The first one is simple to prove, if $k$ = scalar then :

> $k*P(1) = 0$ , always, since $P(1)=0$   (is this logic right?)

But for addition, im not sure how to approach it?

> $P(1) + P(1) = 0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're more or less correct. Your "proof" just needs a little polishing and a slight adjustment.

First, suppose $k \in \mathbb{R}$ (a scalar) and let $f,g \in W$ ($f$ and $g$ are two members of your set $W$).

You need to show that $k\cdot f \in W$ and $f+g \in W$.

First, closure under scalar multiplication: Yep, $kf(1)=0$ because $f(1)=0$. Also, since $f \in P_2$ certainly $kf \in P_2$ (scaling doesn't magically raise the degree of the polynomial). Thus $kf \in W$.

Next, closure under addition: This needs to be adjusted a bit. You need $2$ arbitrary members of $W$ where your notation could be interpreted as the same element added to itself. So instead... $(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=0+0=0$ since $f,g \in W$. Also, $f+g \in P_2$ (since adding polynomials doesn't raise their degree). Thus $f+g \in W$.

One last thing, technically you also need to make sure $W$ isn't empty in order to conclude it is a subspace, but I suppose that's "obvious" for this one. :)  If not, notice that ${\bf 0} \in P_2$ (the zero polynomial) and ${\bf 0}(1)=0$ so ${\bf 0} \in W$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feed back, makes perfect sense! 
Could you give me one hint for another problem on this question?
How could I find a basis for W?

Comment: Sure. If $f(1)=0$ then $f(x) = g(x) \cdot (x-1)$ for some $g(x)$. So your basis has to be several polynomials which have a factor "$x-1$". Next, $\dim(P_2)=2+1=3$ but $W$ has the extra "$f(1)=0$" condition placed on it, so it would make sense to guess that $\dim(W)=2$. Thus look for $2$ polynomials with factor $x-1$ (one of degree 1 and one of degree 2). Good luck! :)